# Gaussian curvature in term of coefficient of first fundamental form and it's derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

> Show that the gaussian curvature $K$ can be written as,
> $$
> \begin{align}
> K=\frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2}
> \left\{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
> \frac12E_{vv}+F_{uv}-\frac12G_{uu} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
> F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
> \frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
> \end{array} \right|\right. \\
> & \left.-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
> 0 & \frac{1}{2} E_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
> \frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
> \frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
> \end{array}\right|\right\} \\
> &
> \end{align}$$
> **Solution:**
> We know that,
> \begin{align}
> x_v\cdot x_{uu}&=F_u-\frac12E_v\tag A\\
> x_v\cdot x_{uv}&=\frac12G_u\tag B
> \end{align}
> differentiating (A) w.r.t. $v$
> $$x_{vv} \cdot x_{uu}+x_v \cdot x_{uuv}=F_{uv}-\frac{1}{2} E_{vv}$$
> differentiating (B) w.r.t $u$
> $$x_{u v} \cdot x_{u v}+x_v \cdot x_{uvu}=\frac{1}{2} G_{u u}$$

subtracting we get,
$$
{x}_{vv} \cdot x_{u u}-x_{u v} \cdot x_{u v}=-\frac{1}{2} E_{v v}+F_{u v}-\frac{1}{2} G_{u u}
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{align}
K &=\frac{e g-f^2}{E G-F^2}\\
& \frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2} \left\{ [x_{uu}\:x_u\:x_v][x_{vv}\:x_u\:x_v]-[x_{uv}\:x_u\:x_v]^2  \right\}\tag1\\
& \frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2} \left\{\left|\begin{array}{lll}
{x}_{u u} \cdot {x}_{v v} & {x}_{u u} \cdot {x}_u & {x}_{u u}\cdot {x}_v \\
{x}_u \cdot {x}_{v v} & {x}_u \cdot {x}_u & {x}_u \cdot {x}_v \\
{x}_v \cdot {x}_{v v} & {x}_v \cdot {x}_u & {x}_v \cdot {x}_v
\end{array}\right|-\left|\begin{array}{lll}
{x}_{u v} \cdot {x}_{u v} & {x}_{u v} \cdot {x}_u & {x}_{u v}: {x}_v \\
{x}_u \cdot {x}_{u v} & {x}_u \cdot {x}_u & {x}_u \cdot {x}_v \\
{x}_v \cdot {x}_{u v} & {x}_v \cdot {x}_u & {x}_v \cdot {x}_v
\end{array}\right|\right\} \tag2\\
& =\frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2} \left\{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{u v} \cdot x_{v v} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
\end{array} \right|\right. \\
& \left.-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathrm{x}_{u v} \cdot {x}_{u v} & \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{E}_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
\frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
\end{array}\right|\right\} \\
& =\frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2}
\left\{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
{x}_{u u} \cdot {x}_{v v}-{x}_{u v} \cdot {x}_{u v} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
\end{array} \right|\right. \\
& \left.-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{2} E_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
\frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
\end{array}\right|\right\} \\
& = \frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2}
\left\{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac12E_{vv}+F_{uv}-\frac12G_{uu} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
\end{array} \right|\right. \\
& \left.-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{2} E_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
\frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
\end{array}\right|\right\}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Question:** I didn't understand how they get from $(1)$ to $(2)$? It will be a great help if anyone explain it.

> notation explanation $[a\:b\:c]=a\cdot(b\times c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $[a,b,c]$ is the determinant of the matrix whose columns are the vectors $a,b,c$. They then seem to be using  $\det(B^\top A) = \det B \det A$ and, similarly, $\det(A^\top A) = \det(A^\top)\det A = (\det A)^2$.

Comment: Thanks again @TedShifrin, now I understand. But one confusion, Like for normal $[a\:b\:c]$ we knew that what will be the column vector look like e.g., $a=a_x\vec{i}+a_y\vec{j}+a_z\vec{k}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{pmatrix}$. I was wondering how $[x_{uu}\:x_u\:x_v]$ will be look like?

Comment: Remember that $x(u,v)$ is the parametrization, so it and its partial derivatives are all vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. We do *not* want to write formulas with all their components.

Comment: If you don't mind can you help me how the following formula come from our above matrix format of $K$,$$K=-\frac{1}{4(EG-F^2)}\left|\begin{pmatrix}
E & F & G\\
E_u & F_u & G_u\\
E_v & F_v & G_v
\end{pmatrix}\right|-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG-F^2}}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{G_u-F_v}{\sqrt{EG-F^2}}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{F_u-E_v}{\sqrt{EG-F^2}}\right)\right]$$Thanks in advance, @TedShifrin

Comment: This is a separate question. You have to do a (non-trivial) calculation, doing your calculus and algebra carefully,

Comment: I ask this question on another thread, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4790016/1167703). Can you help me with that? @TedShifrin