# How to convert the formula for Gaussian curvature of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

In my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784133/) I was asking for some clarification on the derivation of gaussian curvature.

$$
\begin{align}
K=&\frac{1}{\left(E G-F^2\right)^2}
\left\{\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac12E_{vv}+F_{uv}-\frac12G_{uu} & \frac{1}{2} E_u & F_u-\frac{1}{2} E_v \\
F_v-\frac{1}{2} G_u & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_v & F & G
\end{array} \right|\right. \\
& \left.-\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{2} E_v & \frac{1}{2} G_u \\
\frac{1}{2} E_v & E & F \\
\frac{1}{2} G_u & F & G
\end{array}\right|\right\} \\
&
\end{align}\tag1$$

Now, I was stuck on another problem where I need to derive another form of Gaussian curvature,

$$
\begin{align}
K=-\frac{1}{4\left(E G-F^2\right)}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
E & F & G \\
E_u & F_u & G_u \\
E_v & F_v & G_v
\end{array}\right|-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{E G-F^2}}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{G_u-F_v}{\sqrt{E G-F^2}}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{F_u-E_v}{\sqrt{E G-F^2}}\right)\right]
\end{align}\tag2
$$

And I didn't see from where to start. I guess from the derivative part might be a good choice,

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{G_u-F_v}{\sqrt{E G-F^2}}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{F_u-E_v}{\sqrt{E G-F^2}}\right)\\
=&\frac{2(EG-F^2)(G_{uu}-E_{vv})-(G_u-F_v)(E_uG+EG_u-2FF_u)+(F_v-E_v)(E_vG+EG_v-2FF_v)}{2\sqrt{EG-F^2}}
\end{align}\tag3
$$
Now it seems not to fit any matrix format. I was wondering how to related the first determinant of the $K$ in $(1)$ with my $(3)$. Because all the second derivative are coming from that part.

Comment: There are no shortcuts. You just have to work it all out (and you can't ignore the other terms; there will be combinations of terms from both). All such formulas are truly a pain to prove.

Comment: Even though I knew that expanding the determinant and work it for all terms can show both of them are same, but I was wondering is there any careful manipulation which convert them directly from $(1)$ to $(2)$ format, @TedShifrin As I need to complete this in a limited time.

Comment: The computation should be done in ten or fifteen minutes. You've wasted more time than that posting the question here.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong every time or my understanding is very poor to catch the right direction.  Thanks for your response @TedShifrin

Comment: It seems like you're not doing basic calculus correctly. I don't see how you're applying the quotient rule and chain rule correctly, to start.